# How to enable Spring MVC metrics in Spring Boot 2x Actuator

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer, spring-boot-2

I'm trying to setup actuator metrics in Spring Boot 2 RESTful app, however - the list of supported metrics below does not include the 
**`http.server.requests`** metric,

which is part of Spring MVC metrics, as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc

Below are the available metrics that are returned:

```
{
    "names": [
        "jvm.threads.states",
        "jvm.memory.used",
        "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
        "jvm.memory.max",
        "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
        "jvm.memory.committed",
        "system.cpu.count",
        "logback.events",
        "tomcat.global.sent",
        "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
        "tomcat.sessions.created",
        "jvm.threads.daemon",
        "system.cpu.usage",
        "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
        "tomcat.global.request.max",
        "tomcat.global.request",
        "tomcat.sessions.expired",
        "jvm.threads.live",
        "jvm.threads.peak",
        "tomcat.global.received",
        "process.uptime",
        "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
        "process.cpu.usage",
        "tomcat.threads.config.max",
        "jvm.classes.loaded",
        "jvm.classes.unloaded",
        "tomcat.global.error",
        "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
        "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
        "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
        "tomcat.threads.current",
        "jvm.gc.pause",
        "jvm.buffer.count",
        "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
        "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
        "tomcat.threads.busy",
        "process.start.time"
    ]
}
```

I have included following dependencies (among all):

```xml
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

**Is there a way to include the `http.server.requests` metric in my Spring Boot 2 application?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out - **you need to do at least one http request to the application itself** - excluding the management endpoints.

Just hitting any url within the app with a browser caused the `http.server.requests` to appear in the list of metrics.